# About Jquery Name,Submit and attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, submit

My J query code looks like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".respond").submit(function(event){
    var $form = $(this);
```

.....

I want to grab the name of the submit button that was clicked...

I tried couple of things like this but it didn't worked...

```
console.log($("$form input:submit").attr("name"));

.... 

console.log($form+$("input:submit").attr("name"));

.....
```

But this works.

```
console.log(".respond input:submit").attr("name"));
```

i don't know why it didn't works when i use $form.

Can someone tell me how do i find the input of that .respond using $form(or $this) .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$form` variable is a jQuery object. As such you cannot simply concatenate it to another object.

If you want to find one element within another, use `find()`:

```
$form.find('input:submit');
```

Or a contextual selector:

```
$('input:submit', $form);
```

Comment: can you say about contextual selector..even i can see this on google

Answer (score 0):

Use find with form to get its descendant, you are concatenating object with string with wont give you what you want. If you want to get the descendants of the object then use `find()`

```
console.log($form.find("input:submit").attr("name"));
```

You can also try using

```
event.target.name
```

Comment: O god thank you...this question  messed me around one hour..Your code works like a charm.